# Navigation in Silverlight is not changing inside the frame

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am new to silverlight. I am using navigation in my application. The main page contains the login page. After validating i have to navigate to the home page. The navigation works fine, but the mainpage is also showing in the form along with the home page.

```
 ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));


<Navigation:Frame Name="ContentFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,55,12,12" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="5">

        </Navigation:Frame>
```

Both the pages are overlapped and shown in the browser. Where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing all your code I can only guess, but it seems like maybe you've laid out your page like this:

```
<!-- Login stuff here -->
<!-- ... -->

<Navigation:Frame Name="ContentFrame">

</Navigation:Frame>
```

Whereas you should have the login stuff inside the `Navigation:Frame`, so that it gets "overwritten" when `Home.xaml` is loaded:

```
<Navigation:Frame Name="ContentFrame">
    <Navigation:Frame.Content>
        <Grid>
            <!-- Login stuff here -->
        </Grid>
    </Navigation:Frame.Content>
</Navigation:Frame>
```

Comment: S You are correct. But when i am trying to stuff inside,its showing an error "Property content is set more than once" whereas there is no content property. Its showing the same error for all the controls.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar `Navigation:Frame` should have one `Navigation:Frame.Content`, which should have one child element (any element).

Comment: How can i add a login page and registration page inside a frame?